# Change process name of Python script

Tags: python, windows, process

Windows Task Manager lists all running processes in the "Processes" tab.
The image name of Python scripts is always `python.exe`, or `pythonw.exe`, or the name of the Python interpreter.

Is there a nice way to change the image name of a Python script, other than changing the name of the Python interpreter?

Comment: I don't think there's any sensible way to do this.  I'd call it a bug in taskman that it doesn't give the rather obvious option to show window titles where available instead of process names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no nice way that I've found to change the name of a running process in Windows, but you can create small .exe stubs with [**ExeMaker**](http://effbot.org/zone/exemaker.htm) rather than resorting to py2exe packaging or copying the interpreter

The exe stub uses its own module name to calculate the .py script invoked.  You should be able to use an exe resource editor to change the icon.

Answer (score 1):

You could use py2exe to turn your Python program into a self-contained executable with whatever name that you choose to give it.