# Make python process name more explicit

Tags: python, windows

When I run the taskmanager, the process name for all Python scripts are the same : `python.exe`. It makes it difficult to know which is which.

**How to change the process name displayed by Windows task manager?**

*Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255444/changing-the-process-name-of-a-python-script) doesn't seem to work for Windows.*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried launching it with a batch file: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13473372/3001761

Comment: you might looking for command line arguments in addition;  http://serverfault.com/q/323795/273019

Comment: @jonrsharpe : with a batch, 1) it creates a `cmd.exe` process in the task manager, it's not more explicit that "python.exe" if you have multiple instances   2) there's still an additional  `python.exe` in the task manager that appears

Comment: Well then maybe you just can't.

Comment: There's a fairly length post on this topic with both windows and linux that I found useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python but most ways seem like a work around then less you are using Linux and even then...

Comment: @Dean219 which precise answer do you think will help for Windows?

Comment: https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle

Comment: There's a few ways for windows a good one was outlined here but included the use of exe maker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155042/change-process-name-of-python-script

Comment: @dsgdfg I just tried, doesn't work for windows, the title is still "python.exe" in the classic windows task manager.