# how to name a subprocess in python Popen?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, subprocess

how can I make it so that instead of this

[image]

(when I bring the task manager on windows), be something more useful like

- "Process A"
- "Process B"
- ...

All of these processes are summoned using subprocess.Popen in python 2.7.

Comment: seems to be related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/427642/is-it-possible-to-set-the-process-name-with-pythonw). but i'm not sure, can someone clarify?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420116/make-python-process-name-more-explicit) appears to have a working solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make python process name more explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420116/make-python-process-name-more-explicit)